# Need to find the angle of adjustment here

Tags: rotation, geometry, cartesian-coordinates

I have 2 sets of points, say AB and CD. They may or may not be in a straight line. I know their x, y co-ordinates and the angles they make with the horizontal plane. I need to adjust the angle that line AB forms with the horizontal plane in such a way that the points AB are perfectly aligned with CD. Meaning, they form a trapezoid. The image will make it clearer:

[image]

Any ideas as how to find the required angle between AB and the horizontal plane? The distance between any of the points should not be changed.

**Important:**
Since I'll be implementing the solution in a browser, all the co-ordinates are read from top, left = 0, 0. I'm rotating around the center, in a clockwise direction.

Comment: Implemented in a browser ? So you'll use HTML-JS ?

Comment: That said : this question belong more to math.stackexchange.com than to stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes. HTML-JS. I've everything in place, just need the math to get the new angle!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want

```
AB x sin angle-AB = Dy - Cy
angle-AB = arcsin((Dy - Cy)/AB)
```

Dy is y coordinate of D

Cy is y coordinate of C

AB is length of AB

angle-AB is angle of AB relative to horizontal line

Comment: Thanks, it gives the angle! But there is a situation, where the line AB can never be aligned with CD without changing its distance. I'm looking into it now. Yours is the closest answer!

Comment: You're right, I did not consider the corner cases. Left as an exercise for the reader. But I'm glad to have helped. :)

Comment: The trick is to change AB's angle to match CD's, then zoom the image on which the points lie in order to align them in a straight line.

Answer (score 1):

Please clarify what you are asking:

You've initially said you know the angles between the lines and horizontal

> I know their x, y co-ordinates and the angles they make with the horizontal plane.

but then you ask for them in the question?

> how to find the required angle between AB and the horizontal plane

Plus AB and CD lengths must be changed to form a parallelogram (as parallelogram has opposite sides equal in length and parallel)

> The distance between any of the points should not be changed.
>   Can't be true

Comment: Please read the question properly. I need to adjust, meaning reset the angle for the line AB to align the points with CD.

Comment: And yes, if you rotate the line AB around A to align the co-ordinates, the distance stays the same.

Comment: If you rotate around A, Bx and By coordinates are surely going to change?

Comment: The distance AB and BD will be reduced, I can't see it any other way. Yes all Other lengths should remain the same

Comment: If you align A with C, and then rotate B around A, then you can have B aligned with D without changing the distance.

Comment: Please can you rephrase the description using standard conventions with lengths in terms of points ie Length AB (or just AB) and the angle you are referring to as ∠A etc. Would make it easier for me to understand. More information can be found on conventions can be found here http://www.purplemath.com/modules/conventn.htm

Comment: You were right, I have to manage the distance between AB in some scenarios. But the formula above did give me the angle required. +1 for the distance thing.